# C# get set error

Tags: c#, get, set

This Form  1

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using Managed.Adb;


namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        AndroidDebugBridge mADB;
        String mAdbPath;
        List<Device> devices = AdbHelper.Instance.GetDevices(AndroidDebugBridge.SocketAddress);


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();



        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e )
        {
            //mAdbPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH");
            mAdbPath = "C:\\Users\\Nadun\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\android-sdk\\platform-tools";
            mADB = AndroidDebugBridge.CreateBridge(mAdbPath + "\\adb.exe", true);
            mADB.Start();

            var list = mADB.Devices;
            textBox1.Text = "" + list.Count;
            foreach (Device item in list)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("");

                listBox1.Items.Add("" + item.Properties["ro.build.product"].ToString() + "-" + item.SerialNumber.ToString() );
            }

            //Console.WriteLine("" + list.Count);
        }



        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            string text = listBox1.GetItemText(listBox1.SelectedItem);
            Form2 f2 = new Form2(text);
           // f2.Phone = "scs";

            SetPhone sp = new SetPhone();
            sp.PhoneModel = "Test";

            this.Visible = false;
            f2.ShowDialog();
        }




    }
}
```

This is Form 2

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {

        private string phone;

        public string Phone
        {
            get { return this.phone; }
            set { this.phone = value; }
        }

        public Form2(string a)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            textBox1.Text = a;
        }



        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Form2 f2 = new Form2();
            //f2.phone = "s";
            //textBox1.Text = f2.Phone;
            SetPhone sp = new SetPhone();
            textBox1.Text = sp.PhoneModel;
            Console.WriteLine("sefsef-"+sp.PhoneModel);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my Class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    class SetPhone
    {
        private string phoneModel;

        public string PhoneModel {

            get { return this.phoneModel; }

            set { this.phoneModel = value; }

        }
    }
}
```

Get always returning empty.i don't know why.

I am trying to set values from  "form1".

i wrote class for that as well.but when i getting values from "form2" it returning empty.i don't know why

Comment: Only show the information we need not your entire forms.

Comment: this is just a simple visual studio form.it would be big help if you can go through it .

Comment: That is not the point for us to go looking through your code. You should only provide what is needed for us to solve your problem. When you declare / when you get or set / when you use / and what is the outcome.

Answer (score 1):

Your `SetPhone` class object which is calling the setter in the button2_click is a local variable, so when you try access the same in Form2_Load using another local variable, it is a completely new object and Get returns an empty string (default value). You should be able to share the `SetPhone` variable across forms, may be using constructor, then it will retain the values set using the `setter`

Comment: Welcome, it is always important to understand the OOPs and how does the object work and carry data around